# Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

Below is the console erros is getting in frontend.
Checked .htaccess in pub, pub/static and root all .htaccess are identical to Magento 2.2.4 version.

js bundling/minification is enabled and  ran full deployment command.

Please let me knwo if some faced this issue earlier or have any solution to this.

> require.min.js:16 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function($){'use strict';(function(r,G,f,v){var J=f("html"),n=f(r),p=f(G),b=f.fancybox=function(){b.open.apply(this,arguments)},I=navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i),B=null,s=G.createTouch!==v,t=function(a){return a&&a.hasOwnProperty&&a instanceof f},q=function(a){return a&&"string"===f.type(a)},E=function(a){return q(a)&&0',image:'',iframe:'",error:'The requested content cannot be loaded.
> Please try again later.
>
> ',closeBtn:'',next:'',prev:''},openEffect:"fade",openSpeed:250,openEasing:"swing",openOpacity:!0,openMethod:"zoomIn",closeEffect:"fade",closeSpeed:250,closeEasing:"swing",closeOpacity:!0,closeMethod:"zoomOut",nextEffect:"elastic",nextSpeed:250,nextEasing:"swing",nextMethod:"changeIn",prevEffect:"elastic",prevSpeed:250,prevEasing:"swing",prevMethod:"changeOut",helpers:{overlay:!0,title:!0},onCancel:f.noop,beforeLoad:f.noop,afterLoad:f.noop,beforeShow:f.noop,afterShow:f.noop,beforeChange:f.noop,beforeClose:f.noop,afterClose:f.noop},group:{},opts:{},previous:null,coming:null,current:null,isActive:!1,isOpen:!1,isOpened:!1,wrap:null,skin:null,outer:null,inner:null,player:{timer:null,isActive:!1},ajaxLoad:null,imgPreload:null,transitions:{},helpers:{},open:function(a,d){if(a&&(f.isPlainObject(d)||(d={}),!1!==b.close(!0)))return f.isArray(a)||(a=t(a)?f(a).get():[a]),f.each(a,function(e,c){var k={},g,h,j,m,l;"object"===f.type(c)&&(c.nodeType&&(c=f(c)),t(c)?(k={href:c.data("fancybox-href")||c.attr("href"),title:c.data("fancybox-title")||c.attr("title"),isDom:!0,element:c},f.metadata&&f.extend(!0,k,c.metadata())):k=c);g=d.href||k.href||(q(c)?c:null);h=d.title!==v?d.title:k.title||"";m=(j=d.content||k.content)?"html":d.type||k.type;!m&&k.isDom&&(m=c.data("fancybox-type"),m||(m=(m=c.prop("class").match(/fancybox.(\w+)/))?m[1]:null));q(g)&&(m||(b.isImage(g)?m="image":b.isSWF(g)?m="swf":"#"===g.charAt(0)?m="inline":q(c)&&(m="html",j=c)),"ajax"===m&&(l=g.split(/\s+/,2),g=l.shift(),l=l.shift()));j||("inline"===m?g?j=f(q(g)?g.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/,""):g):k.isDom&&(j=c):"html"===m?j=g:!m&&(!g&&k.isDom)&&(m="inline",j=c));f.extend(k,{href:g,type:m,content:j,title:h,selector:l});a[e]=k}),b.opts=f.extend(!0,{},b.defaults,d),d.keys!==v&&(b.opts.keys=d.keys?f.extend({},b.defaults.keys,d.keys):!1),b.group=a,b._start(b.opts.index)},cancel:function(){var a=b.coming;a&&!1!==b.trigger("onCancel")&&(b.hideLoading(),b.ajaxLoad&&b.ajaxLoad.abort(),b.ajaxLoad=null,b.imgPreload&&(b.imgPreload.onload=b.imgPreload.onerror=null),a.wrap&&a.wrap.stop(!0,!0).trigger("onReset").remove(),b.coming=null,b.current||b._afterZoomOut(a))},close:function(a){b.cancel();!1!==b.trigger("beforeClose")&&(b.unbindEvents(),b.isActive&&(!b.isOpen||!0===a?(f(".fancybox-wrap").stop(!0).trigger("onReset").remove(),b._afterZoomOut()):(b.isOpen=b.isOpened=!1,b.isClosing=!0,f(".fancybox-item, .fancybox-nav").remove(),b.wrap.stop(!0,!0).removeClass("fancybox-opened"),b.transitionsb.current.closeMethod)))},play:function(a){var d=function(){clearTimeout(b.player.timer)},e=function(){d();b.current&&b.player.isActive&&(b.player.timer=setTimeout(b.next,b.current.playSpeed))},c=function(){d();p.unbind(".player");b.player.isActive=!1;b.trigger("onPlayEnd")};if(!0===a||!b.player.isActive&&!1!==a){if(b.current&&(b.current.loop||b.current.index

Comment: You can refer this link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371918/mismatched-anonymous-define-module

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `defined` use `require` Like this:

```
require([
    'jquery',
    "jquery/ui"
], function($){
    'use strict';

    //Your code here
});
```